# How to check if PDP context settings are valid and ready?

Tags: gsm, at-command, ras

I'm heading with problem of determine if set PDP context is ready. I thought that it will be enough to check CGREG to determine the status, but it only returns GPRS registration state.

Also CGACT will return 1 if context is active, and I'm just interested if APN and user are valid OR if network/SIM/modem accepted my settings. I assume cgact=1 will return errors if something is not valid, but I don't want to do that and I want to pass the responsibility for connection to the RAS.

I want to check it before I will give the control over the connection to Windows RAS.

Comment: Maybe I am just being thick, but I don't understand why you don't want to use +CGACT?

Comment: Because I will open context - I don't want to do that on serial interface, I want that RAS using internal mechanism will handle setting up the Internet connection.

To use it in such way I have to connect, then disconnect and I still don't know if I have or not to wait for some time to pass it to handle it by RAS.